Short story I read a while back, from aliens' point of view on humanity
It started off with the aliens not reaching out because they didn't think that humans were advanced enough, but then they saw how they created atomic bombs and recklessly destroyed each other, they became terrified. Humans find out about alien life and start attacking, but at the end of the story, a team of human medics try and help survivors.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.   Where and when did you read this?

Thank you! I read  this I think about a month ago, no idea where I read this. Was recommending it to a friend and completely forgot where it was from.

This is First Contact, Part 1 by DalekTeaService.
Aliens are terrified of humanity and hide. The story ends with the arrival of a human ship at a colony suffering a plague.

“We are The Doctors Without Borders,” she said, speaking slowly and carefully. “We are here to help.”

